# Puppet - How to write yaml files based on Role/Profile method

Tags: linux, puppet, hiera

I've added our infrastructure setup to puppet, and used roles and profiles method. Each profile resides inside a group, based on their nature. For example, Chronyd setup and Message of the day are in "base" group, nginx-related configuration is in "app" group. Also, on the roles, each profile is added to the corresponding group. For example for memcached we have the following:

```
class role::prod::memcache inherits role::base::debian {

  include profile::app::memcache
}
```

The `profile::app::memcached` has been set up like this :

```
class profile::app::memcache {

  service { 'memcached':
    ensure => running,
    enable => true,
    hasrestart => true,
    hasstatus  => true,
  }
}
```

and for `role::base::debian` I have :

```
class role::base::debian {

  include profile::base::motd
  include profile::base::chrony

}
```

The above structure has proved to be flexible enough for our infrastructure. Adding services and creating new roles could not been easier than this. But now I face a new problem. I've been trying to separate data from logic, write some yaml files to keep the data there, using Hiera version 5. Been looking through internet for a couple of days, but I cannot deduct how to write my hiera files based on the structure I have. I tried adding `profile::base::motd` to common.yaml and did a puppet lookup, it works fine, but I could not append chrony to common.yaml. Puppet lookup returns nothing with the following common.yaml contents :

```
---
profile::base::motd::content: This server access is restricted to authorized users only. All activities on this system are logged. Unauthorized access will be liable to prosecution.'
profile::base::chrony::servers: 'ntp.centos.org'
profile::base::chrony::service_enable: 'true'
profile::base::chrony::service_ensure: 'running'
```

Motd lookup works fine. But the rest, no luck. `puppet lookup profile::base::chrony::servers` returns with no output. Don't know what I'm missing here. Would really appreciate the community's help on this one.

Also, using hiera, is the following enough code for a service puppet file?

```
class profile::base::motd {

        class { 'motd':
        }
}
```

PS : I know I can add yaml files inside modules to keep the data, but I want my .yaml files to reside in one place (e.g. $PUPPET_HOME/environment/production/data) so I can manage the code with git.

Comment: I don't see any glaring errors in what you present, but I can't say more without a [mre].

Comment: I don't know what is really going on here, but the `puppet lookup` behavior you describe is not consistent with the Hiera data you present being in the data hierarchy that Puppet is relying upon.  Are you running those `puppet lookup` commands as the same user that the puppetserver process runs as?

Comment: @JohnBollinger All of the files have been edited with root and `puppet lookup` is run with root as well

Comment: How the files were edited is irrelevant.  Their names and locations matter, and the applicable Hiera configuration, and the UID of the puppet process performing the lookup.  I am still waiting for that MRE -- follow the hyperlink above for more information about what we mean by that term and about ways to go about constructing one.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I found the issue and will update the answer accordingly, thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that in `init.pp` file inside the puppet module itself, the variable `$content` was assigned a value. Removing the value fixed the problem.